# goog.cryp.Hmac cannot reproduce result from crypt from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, hmac, google-closure-library

I am trying to reproduce HMAC signature described [here](https://github.com/looker/looker_embed_sso_examples/blob/master/node_example.js#L58).

The example is using `crypt` from `nodejs`, however, in my case, I need to use the google closure library. So I tried to reproduce the HMAC signature using the `goog.crypt.Hmac` library.

Below are my experiment code.

```js
let crypto = require('crypto');
require("google-closure-library");

goog.require("goog.crypt.Hmac");
goog.require("goog.crypt");
goog.require('goog.crypt.Sha1');

function forceUnicodeEncoding(string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string));
}

function nodejs_crypto(string_to_sign, secret) {
    signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret)
        .update(forceUnicodeEncoding(string_to_sign))
        .digest('base64')
        .trim();
    return signature
}

function goog_crypto(string_to_sign, secret) {
    const hmac = new goog.crypt.Hmac(new goog.crypt.Sha1(), goog.crypt.stringToByteArray(secret));
    const hash = hmac.getHmac(forceUnicodeEncoding(string_to_sign));
    return hash.toString()
}

const string_to_sign = "message";
const secret = "secret";
const sig1 = nodejs_crypto(string_to_sign, secret);
const sig2 = goog_crypto(string_to_sign, secret);

console.log(sig1);
// DK9kn+7klT2Hv5A6wRdsReAo3xY=

console.log(sig2);
// 12,175,100,159,238,228,149,61,135,191,144,58,193,23,108,69,224,40,223,22
```

I can hardly find any examples online for `goog.crypt.Hmac`.

Here are my problems:

1. I am not sure if `goog_crypto` is implemented correctly.
2. why `hash.String()` returns an array-like thing?
3. how can I convert the hmac hash to base64 string using the closure lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your goog_crypto function looks right, since the result is identical, albeit represented in base64 vs array of integers (bytes)
2. The return value of `getHmac`, i.e `hash` in your code, is an array of integers - as [documented here](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.crypt.Hmac.html) ... an `array.toString()` is much the same as `array.join()`
3. if you want your goog_crypto function to return base64, use nodejs Buffer toString to do the hard work for you

i.e

```
function goog_crypto(string_to_sign, secret) {
    const hmac = new goog.crypt.Hmac(new goog.crypt.Sha1(), goog.crypt.stringToByteArray(secret));
    const hash = hmac.getHmac(forceUnicodeEncoding(string_to_sign));
    return Buffer.from(hash).toString('base64');
}
```

Since `hash` is an array of `Numbers`, `Buffer.from(hash)` creates a Buffer from the numbers in `hash` - `buffer.toString('base64')` returns the buffer data *encoded* in base64

---

Regarding point 1: to prove the results you are getting in your code are the same

```js
const sig1 = "DK9kn+7klT2Hv5A6wRdsReAo3xY=";
const sig2 = '12,175,100,159,238,228,149,61,135,191,144,58,193,23,108,69,224,40,223,22';
const sig1AsNumArrayString = atob(sig1).split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).toString();
console.log(sig2 === sig1AsNumArrayString)
```